# How inversion has been used in following sentence?

Tags: inversion

An extract from news paper,

"In fact, during 1971 war, Pakistani warplanes were parked at Tehran Airport as a tactical backup had West Pakistan also crumbled like the East."

"I know that inversion is used in negative meaning or with adverbial phrase ,but here in above sentence there is no adverbial or negative. However it has been used."

What is the reason and why?

May be only for emphasis. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *In fact, during 1971 war, Pakistani warplanes were parked at Tehran*
> *Airport as a tactical backup had West Pakistan also crumbled like the*
> *East*.

A conditional construction with the omission of "if", and subject-auxiliary inversion:

> *a tactical backup  if West Pakistan had also crumbled like the East*.

Perhaps not found much nowadays, though it's grammatically fine and understandable. Note that “if” could be replaced by the PP “in case”:

> ... *a tactical backup in case West Pakistan had also crumbled like the*
> *East*

Answer (score 2):

It reads a bit oddly in this case, but it is the (rather literary) use of inversion for counter-factual conditionals:

> had West Pakistan also crumbled like the East

means precisely the same as

> if West Pakistan had also crumbled like the East.

You can find lots of examples in (particularly older) writing: "Had he wanted to ... ", "Should they come, ... ", "Did they but suspect ... "